# Passing data from one page to another using Node, Express & EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've got the following routes set up:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {});
});

router.post('/application', function(req, res) {
  res.render('application', {twitchLink : req.query.twitchLink});
});
```

I've got the two views set up properly.

This is what I've got in the 'index' view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/application", method="post", role="form">
    <input type="url" name="twitchLink" required>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Submitting this form does take me to the application view.

```
<script>var twitchLink = <%- JSON.stringify(twitchLink) %></script>
<script>console.log(twitchLink)</script>
```

This should log out the link that I submitted, right?
However, I get these two lines:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
Uncaught ReferenceError: twitchLink is not defined
```

Comment: have you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put quotes around `<%- JSON.stringify(twitchLink) %>`, like this:

```
var twitchLink = '<%- JSON.stringify(twitchLink) %>'
```

In your example, it will come out as:

```
var twitchLink = foo.bar.com
```

What you want is:

```
var twitchLink = 'foo.bar.com'
```